# Socket.io - why all users can't have different names?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make my own game in JavaScript and Node.JS but can't make my players have different names !

Source code for the Node.JS server: http://pastebin.com/tc4utzWT
Source code for the client : http://pastebin.com/YuDS4qtH

Comment: Hi, can you isolate the problem and expose only the minimum code that is necessary to understand the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, your question is a really broad one. It will be too difficult for us to look through all of your code and find the problem. Instead, ask a new question showing us what you've tried and where specifically you're encountering a problem.

Comment: Everything is ok with question, i can tell it from 15 seconds that it's all because of single connection for all users.. I've done full livechat company software with socket.io :-) two times lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all because you have single socket connection shared between all users. Try using "rooms" of socket.io You can find more info here:

http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/